# How do I ensure the http post has executed fully when run in a loop in angular 7?

Tags: angular

I am calling HTTP POST in a loop in angular 7. How do I ensure that saveMembers() and saveTasks() have completely executed? I am expecting both to be executed parallelly.

```
function saveMembers() {
    // Add resource
    members.forEach(resource => {
        this.addMembers(resource.name);
    });
}

function saveTasks() {
    // Add tasks
    tasks.forEach(task => {
        this.addTasks(task.name);
    });
}

function addMembers(resourceName) {
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Members', { "name": resourceName }).
        subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }, (error) => { });
}

function addTasks(taskName) {
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Task', { "task": taskName }).
        subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }, (error) => { });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular usually http commands are performed using Observables, and this seems your case as well.

In you code you create as many Observables as there are `members` and `tasks` and then `subscribe` separately to each of them. Given the asynchronous nature of http calls, you end up not knowing when the processing is complete.

On the other hand, if you want to be notified when all Observables have completed, then you can use the `forkJoin` function, with a code that could look like this

```
function saveMembers$() {
    // Returns an array of Observables, each one representing an Http Post
    return members.map(resource => {
        return this.addMembers(resource.name);
    });
}

function saveTasks$() {
    // Returns an array of Observables, each one representing an Http Post
    return tasks.map(task => {
        return this.addTasks(task.name);
    });
}

function addMembers$(resourceName) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Members', { "name": resourceName }).
        pipe(catchError(err => {
          // create a structure with the relevant error info
          const errStructure = ....
          // return an Observable which emits the errStructure
          return of(errStructure);
        });
}

function addTasks(taskName) {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Task', { "task": taskName }).
        pipe(catchError(err => {
          // create a structure with the relevant error info
          const errStructure = ....
          // return an Observable which emits the errStructure
          return of(errStructure);
        });
}

// finally execute all the Post in parallel with forkJoin
forkJoin([...saveMembers$(), ...saveTasks$()]).subscribe(
  resp => {
     // resp is an array containing either the value returned by the post
     // or the error info. resp follows the same order as the Observables passed
     // to forkJoin
  }
)
```

Comment: You should make sure to return the observable in the `addTasks` function as well as inside the `map`s of the calling functions.

Comment: But otherwise, great answer. Well explained!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { mergeAll } from "rxjs/operators";

const members = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const tasks = [11, 22, 33];

function saveMembers() {
  const stream = of(...tasks.map(task => addMembers(task)));
  stream
    .pipe(mergeAll())
    .subscribe(
      val => console.log("saving task", val),
      () => console.log("error"),
      () => console.log("completed saving tasks")
    );
}

function saveTasks() {
  const stream = of(...members.map(member => addMembers(member)));
  stream
    .pipe(mergeAll())
    .subscribe(
      val => console.log("saving member", val),
      () => console.log("error"),
      () => console.log("completed saving members")
    );
}

function addMembers(resourceName) {
  // Faking the observable using rxjs 'of' utility
  // Note that you don't want to subscribe to the observable yet
  return of(resourceName);

  // return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Members', { "name": resourceName });
}

function addTasks(taskName) {
  // Faking the observable using rxjs 'of' utility
  // Note that you don't want to subscribe to the observable yet
  return of(taskName);

  // return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'Task', { "task": taskName });
}

saveMembers();
saveTasks();
```

So within `saveMembers()` I'm creating an array of observables by mapping calls to `addMembers()`. Then I'm creating a stream from the array of observables using `of` utility of rxjs. Then I pipe in `mergeAll` operator and subscribe to the new stream. Once all the observables within the stream complete the stream itself will complete. So in the 3rd callback to the `subscribe()` function you can put logic that goes after all the POSTs are completed.
You can find more about rxjs operators like `mergeAll` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators).

> I'm faking the async POST request in `addMembers()` using `of` utility of rxjs. You will have to return the actual POST request observable but make sure not to subscribe to it. It will be subscribed to in the `saveMembers()` function instead. In general you return statement is commented out in the `addMembers()`.